# Identifying the splitting field of $x^{4}-2x^{2}-3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, splitting-field

> Identify the splitting field F of $f(x)=x^{4}-2x^{2}-3$ over
>   $\mathbb{Q}$ and determine $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
>   $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

**My thoughts:** Clearly $f(x)$ isn't irreducible, since $f(x)=(x^{2}+1)(x^{2}-3)$.
So, the roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm i,\pm\sqrt{3}$. As far as I understand,
I need to find an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$ and
$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Could you please give me a hint to find such
isomorphism?

Comment: Maybe try something like $i+\sqrt{3}$ which should lie in $F$ but not in any of the subfields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbf Q(i,\sqrt3)=\mathbf Q(i+\sqrt3$).

Indeed $(i+\sqrt3)^3=8i$, so $i=\frac18(i+\sqrt 3)^3$ and $\sqrt3=(i+\sqrt 3)-\frac18(i+\sqrt 3)^3$.

Note it is generated by $i-\sqrt3$ as well. More generally you may try to obtain $i$ from $i+\lambda\sqrt 3$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: I understood the answer you provided. But today I was going through this exercise again and something strikes me... how do I prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+i)$ is a field? I know how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field, but I don't see how I can do it in this case.

Comment: Do you mean ‘how to prove the existence of inverses’? $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ is the set of rational functions in$\alpha$, and if $u=\dfrac{p(\alpha)}{q(\alpha)}\ne 0$ its inverse is $\dfrac{q(\alpha)}{p(\alpha)}$. Unless we don't have the same definition of  $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$.

Comment: I thought that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\left\{ a+b\alpha\,:\,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\right\} $. To denote a field of fractions I thought the notation in use would be $\mathbb{Q}(X)$, where $X$ is the indeterminate.

Comment: This is true, but it's not the definition. Actually, one shows more generally that if $\alpha$ is algebraic (i.e. is a root of a polynomial equation), then $\mathbf Q(\alpha)=\mathbf Q[\alpha]$, and that if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $d$, a basis of this field as a $\mathbf Q$-vector space is $\;\{1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{d-1}\}$. This result yields what you thought for $d=2$.

Comment: I think you meant $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/<p(x)>$, right? Here $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. My problem was that I thought that $\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{3})=\left\{ a+b(i+\sqrt{3})\,:\,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\right\} $, but $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+i)\,:\,\mathbb{\mathbb{Q}}]=4$ so $\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{3})=\left\{ a+b(i+\sqrt{3})+c(i+\sqrt{3})^{2}+d(i+\sqrt{3})^{3}\,:\,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\right\} $.

Comment: Formally, $\mathbf Q[\alpha]$ is the image of the polynomial ring $\mathbf Q[X]$ under the map $X\mapsto \alpha$ and $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ is its field of fractions. It happens that, when $\alpha$ is algebraic, they're the same thing.  Now  $\mathbf Q[\alpha]$ can't be  just $\{a+b(1+\sqrt 3)\}$, because  it is an extension of degree $4$. What you wrote works only for quadratic extensions.